# Spring Boot Thymeleaf GetParameter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, getparameter

How to get to the controller the user entered data at html - checkBox and select list. I have used Thymeleaf and SpringBoot.

```
<form id="register-form" th:object="${worker}" th:action="@{/worker/save}"
                                          method="post"
                                          role="form">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" id="firstName" tabindex="1"
                                                   class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value=""/>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" th:field="*{secondName}" id="secondName" tabindex="1"
                                                   class="form-control" placeholder="Second Name" value=""/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Bithday" type="text"
                                                   th:field="*{dateBirth}" id="datepicker"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input type="checkbox" value="java"/>JAVA Skill
                                            </label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="first"> First level</option>
                                                <option value="second"> Second level</option>
                                                <option value="third"> Third level</option>
                                                <option value="fourth"> Fourth level</option>
                                                <option value="fifth"> Fifth level</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input th:field="*{phpSkill}" type="checkbox" value="php"/>PHP Skill
                                            </label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect2">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="first"> First level</option>
                                                <option value="second"> Second level</option>
                                                <option value="third"> Third level</option>
                                                <option value="fourth"> Fourth level</option>
                                                <option value="fifth"> Fifth level</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                <input th:field="*{javascriptSkill}" type="checkbox"
                                                       value="javascript"/>JAVA
                                                SCRIPT Skill
                                            </label>
                                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect3">
                                                <option value=""></option>
                                                <option value="first"> First level</option>
                                                <option value="second"> Second level</option>
                                                <option value="third"> Third level</option>
                                                <option value="fourth"> Fourth level</option>
                                                <option value="fifth"> Fifth level</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <hr/>


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                    <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit"
                                                           tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register"
                                                           value="Register Now"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

This is my Controller code: I need to receive here select option value and check box value

```
@Controller
public class WorkerController {



     private WorkerServ workerServ;

        @Autowired
        public WorkerController(WorkerServ workerServ) {
            this.workerServ = workerServ;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/worker/register")
        public String saveWorker(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("worker", new Worker());
            return "signupWorker";
        }
        @RequestMapping(value = "worker/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveWorker(Worker worker) {
            String firstName = worker.getFirstName();
            String secondName = worker.getSecondName();
            String dateBith = worker.getDateBirth();


            workerServ.registerWorker(firstName, secondName, dateBith, null);
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use javaSkill and level in CheckBox and Select, your model ***"worker"*** should have the variables with getter and setter!

CheckBox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="javaSkill" th:checked="*{javaSkill}" />
```

Select:

```
<select th:field="*{level}">
  <option th:value="first" th:text="First Level"></option>
  <option th:value="second" th:text="Second Level"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and effective example for the dropdown menu

> **Example**

```
<select class="form-control" th:value="${appointment.location}" name="location" id="location">
                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" > -- select the location --</option>
                        <option>Boston</option>
                        <option>New York</option>
                        <option>Chicago</option>
                        <option>San Francisco</option>
                    </select>
```

if you access `location` value in the controller then you will be able to get the dropdown value

> similar one goes to check box